# Replacing\Changing Alpha in RGBA JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, rgba

I'm trying to change the Alpha in RGBA, from some reason replace acts strange and instead of resulting with: "rgba(30, 43, 2, A)" i end up with: "A".

Here is the code:

```
var color="rgba(30, 43, 2, 0.498039)";
color = color.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/gi,"A");
alert(color);
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/365WR/)

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to — searching for a chunk that starts at the beginning of the string and ends at a right parenthesis, and replacing it with "A".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't get your logic but you can do this :

```
color = color.replace(/[\d\.]+\)$/g, 'A)')
```

What it matches :

- `[\d\.]+` : a combination of `.` and digits
- `\)` : the end parenthesis
- `$` : the end of the string (you can remove it if you don't want to ensure it's the end of the string)

Comment: it say: You can accept an answer in 11 minutes, but its a correct one, i will accept it when timer zeroes. can you explain your regex? i dont understand it at all and it seems much more simple than what i found. sorry noob at regex

Comment: @user1725378 I added an explanation. I didn't make it fancy

Answer (score 0):

Match the last digit + paranthesis like '1 )' and replace with any alpha value

```js
color.replace(/[\d.]+\)$/g, '0.15)')
```